# How can I get all 'id' numbers from array of array, and make a new array of them?

Tags: arrays

I need to get all id from activities in this array of arrays.
options can be an array too.
Please check image below:
[image]

I have done

> const allActivities = activities.map(activity => {return
> activity.options.map(act => { return act.activities})  })
> and got this
> 1)]
> 0: [Array(3)] 1: [Array(2)] 2: [Array(5)] 3: Array(2) 0: (2) [{…},
> {…}] 1: (2) [{…}, {…}]

length: 2
**proto**: Array(0)

can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please _tag_ appropriately (this should at least have the programming language tagged as well), please format your code properly (_not_ as a quote.)

Comment: Also, share input and as well as expected output.

Comment: Could you show or provide complete array

Answer (score 0):

As other users have suggested, you should put the entire array and also which languague you are using.

What you can do is basically some iterations as it is the easiest way to access that data and then store it into a variable, just like this:

```
for each element in vector 
    for each element in vector[i].subvector1  //Each of the inner vectors into that 25 result vector
       for each element in vector[i].subvector1[j].options
           for each element in vector[i].subvector1[j].options[z].activities
               activities_id += vector[i].subvector1[j].options[z].activities[y]
```

This is just an aproach written in some pseudocode, but I think the idea is clear.